# XCode 6 beta Application Templates are not include

Tags: ios8, xcode6

Now i have installed XCode 6 beta.

But when i open it , i can't see any Application Templates like following pic.

I want to test custom keyboard for iOS8.

[image]

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to create an application from the screen you've shown.

After that you go to **File > New > Target**

[image]

And then select **Custom Keyboard**.

[image]